# How to fix scaling of HTML website elements to fit all devices

Tags: html, css

I've only learned some HTML, and I am having trouble with HTML's elements using `px` unit.
When I look on the website through my pc, it looks perfectly fine, but when I try it on any other device, the elements are in the wrong place.

Image of mobile website:

[image: Image of website Mobile]

Image of PC website:

[image: Image of website my PC]

There is my style.css:

```css
.first {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.second {
    color: white;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    font-size: 52px;
}

.third {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.fourth {
    background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185);
    width: 55%;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 22%;
}

.fifth {
    color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
}

.sixth {
    color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.seventh {
    background-color: rgb(38, 0, 255);
    color: white;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border: transparent;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 228px;
    padding-right: 32px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    margin-left: 405px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.eighth {
   margin-top: -691px;
   margin-left: 90%;
}

.ninth {
    background-color: rgb(0, 100, 255);
    color: white;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px; 
}

.tenth {
    background-color: rgb(0, 81, 255);
    color: white;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px; 
}

.eleventh {
    color: rgb(116, 116, 116);
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.twelveth {
    color: rgb(116, 116, 116);
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

.thirteenth {
    color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `px` unit to `%` unit. This means that whatever the screen size is, the element will be in the same position (some value of attributes can change to fit the new screen, like: `margin`, `padding`, etc).